# Guice Binder hasBind functionality

Tags: java, guice

Is there any way to check if an implementation exists for an interface?

For example, the method "hasBind" below does not exist:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // do something like this:
        if (!hasBind(SomeInterface.class)) {
            bind(SomeInterface.class).to(MyOtherSomeInterface.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the order of applied modules does not matter in guice, you cannot detect if a binding exists before the injector was created, see [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-guice/s8ny04NcIJE).

The proposed solution is to create a starting module with default bindings and use `Modules.overwrite` to apply ypur additional bindings.